# Transit through Hong Kong Airport - visa requirement?

Tags: visas, transit, hong-kong

As a Vietnamese national, on a New Zealand student visa, I'm transiting via Hong Kong on my flight home for the holidays. Will I need a transit visa, flying with Cathay?

Comment: Your visa is only valid for New Zealand as so you will always travel as a Vietnamese National. If you book the ticket as New Zealand to Vietnam then you do not need a visa. But if you book it separate as New Zealand - Hong Kong and Hong Kong - Vietnam, then you need a visum.

Answer (score 4):

[According to Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=VN&DE=SGN&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=HKG&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines for visa information:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Those who are
>   in direct (Air to Air or Air to Sea) transit if holding confirmed
>   onward bookings, continuing their journey within 48 hours and not
>   leaving the transit lounge.

If you can meet these conditions and remain airside at Hong Kong airport (without passing immigration), this says you can transit without a visa. You would need a visa to actually enter Hong Kong, such as to see the city or stay in a hotel if you have a long layover.

This can also be seen on [the website of the Hong Kong Immigration Department](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html), where Vietnam is listed as Visa Required, but not with the "*" symbol that says a visa is required for "those who are in transit and remain on the airside." [Wikipedia lists Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Hong_Kong#Visa_required_nationals) on the list of countries whose nationals "are not required to have a visa to transit airside if they remain within the airport transit area."