# Transit visa for 6.5 hour layover Hong Kong

Tags: visas, transit, hong-kong, bangladeshi-citizens, canadian-residents

I am traveling from Canada to Australia via Hong Kong. I am trying to confirm if I need a transit Visa in HK. I have a Bangladeshi passport and I'm a Canadian PR. I am planning to fly in a week and I'm trying to find out if I might need a transit Visa for a 6.5 hour layover. I'd like to know what my options are at this point.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/95585/19233

Answer (score 13):

Hong Kong does not permit nationals of Bangladesh (and several other countries) to transit without a visa, not even in the international transit area of the airport. If you try to go without one, the airline may deny boarding.

You have two obvious options at this point:

First, you could try to obtain a [visit/transit visa from Hong Kong](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit_transit.html). Their official web site says that this may take up to four weeks. Your Hong Kong visa application must be submitted to the [China Visa Application Center](https://www.visaforchina.org/) which serves your province. It seems unlikely that you will receive this visa before your flight.

Or, you can change your flight itinerary to transit through a different country. Likely you will have to purchase tickets on another airline.

Comment: The Chinese Visa Application Centers are not responsible for issuing/processing visas to Hong Kong. Hong Kong has its own authorities to issue those visas. Those authorities are listed on the "Applying" tab of the https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit_transit.html#secondTab page that you posted.

Comment: @Dreamer Would you care to explain what you are referring to? Aside from mailing your application to Hong Kong, which I suppose you could do, that site refers you to your local Chinese consular mission. Which then refers you to the Chinese Visa Application Center.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're screwed.  Go here:

https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html#notes

[image]

You are unfortunately a **caret symbol country**:

[image]

Wikipedia for example summarizes it as:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Hong_Kong#Visa_required_nationals

## Nationals of the following countries are required to possess a visa for any type of entry into Hong Kong (including as tourists) *and for transit airside (even if they remain within the airport transit area)* :

- Bangladesh

[image]